# Packaging typescript app using zeit's pkg (lib.d.ts not found)

Tags: node.js, typescript, zeit-pkg

I am trying to package a typescript app using zeit's `pkg` that was compiled to `.js` using the typescript compiler `tsc`. The package seems to be created without any issues, however when I try to run the exe I get the error:

```
TypeScriptError: File 'C:/snapshot/script/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts' not found.
```

So I added every `.d.ts` files as assets in `package.json`:

```
"assets": "**/*.d.ts"
```

...but that didn't work.

Anyone knows why it cannot find the file even thought its packaged? I verified with `--debug` and its listed as packaged.

Thank!

Comment: This post describes a strategy that worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56737410/packaging-a-typescript-project-into-an-executable