# Packaging a Typescript project into an executable

Tags: typescript, exe

How can I package a Typescript project into an executable?

As I was looking for a while and couldn't find any, I used for now node to achieve the above. I'm publishing what I did, hoping someone will find it useful.

---

1. Compile Typescript project into node (according to [this](https://medium.com/isovera/3-ways-to-implement-typescript-into-your-project-39a2c9d7f850)). I personally used tsc.

***Note:*** when using webpack I came across some problems with net and fs.
Adding the following to Webpack.config.js helped:

```
node: {
  net: 'empty',
  fs: 'empty'
}
```

(References [here](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/665) and [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/447))

2. After compiling the project, I ran it using node (for validation only).
3. To create an exe file from node project, I used [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg).

The tsconfig.json I used is:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist/server",
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types", "./typings"
    ]},
    "exclude": [
        "dist",
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

And added the following to the package.json ([reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html))

```
"build-ts": "tsc --project ./tsconfig.json"
```

Comment: Please separate your answer from your question. You are allowed to answer and accept your own question.

Answer (score 0):

try building it into javascript and after that use https://github.com/vercel/pkg

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).